# Does MarkLogic NoSQL databases duplicate data?

Tags: marklogic, nosql

I have heard that `MarkLogic` is of a new breed called **multi-model** databases and the fact that they tend allow users to model data in different way i.e relational, xml, json etc. Does it mean that data in `MarkLogic` is stored in all the available models physically (resulting in multiple copies of the same data) or there is just one copy of data and the model is decided dynamically.

Comment: Tell us which product you are actually talking about and we might be able to answer.

Comment: MarkLogic to be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarkLogic stores each document in a database. Physically the database stores each document in an on-disk locations called a *Forest*. Each database has one or more forests, and each forest can be on any host in the cluster. By default MarkLogic stores each document just once, in a forest selected automatically.

A hosts that needs a document will query to find out which forest the document is in, and fetch it from that forest. That forest can be local or remote.

For high availability, a forest can be configured as a replica of another forest on another host in the cluster. If every forest in a database has its own replica on a different host, then a host failure can be handled automatically without loss of data. As of MarkLogic 7 the database will only query the master forests, not the replicas. So the replica data is passive, not active. However that could change in some future release.

For disaster recovery, a database can be configured as a replica of a database in a different ("foreign") cluster.

See the docs for more:

- https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/forests
- https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/config-local-failover
- https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/failover
- https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/arch/data-management